# What's the technical term of "string ID"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've two columns in my MySQL table, with unique values:

- `id` *(type: Integer, auto-increment)*
- `key` *(type: Varchar, to make URLs pretty, e.g. "example.com/entry/my-string-id/")*

I don't want to name the column `key`, because it's a reserved word and way too vague.

How would you name this column?

I know, it's not a specific programming question, but I'd like to have a correct structure and it's kinda part of the architecture. :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
I was looking for the word "SLUG". Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about Module/Resource/Item/Content ID/Code? I don't think there's a strictly 'correct' term for it.

Comment: JWLim: Thanks for your reply. I know, it's a weird question, but I guess, I heard a correct term before.

Comment: You can call it UID - since it will be a unique identifier. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier I guess this term is technical enough

Comment: UID as @YuriyGalanter mentioned, or URN. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Comment: This question seems to be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the column name "`uri`" for this type of identifier, Uniform Resource Identifer. Another alternative is "urn", if you want to be more specific.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI

We avoid using the name `URL` because that is more specific, includes the protocol, etc. We get the protocol and hostname from another source, and don't store it over and over.

---

We name the auto_increment primary key of the table `id`, to distinguish it from a foreign key, which we normally name `table_id`, where `table` identifies the referenced table. That means that join predicates are normally of the pattern `parent.id = child.parent_id`

Comment: I was looking for the word "slug". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, I find that one of the harder parts of writing code is sometimes finding appropriate names for things.  One of the advantages of SQL over other programming paradigms is that, when using SQL queries, you don't have to find names for a bunch of intermediate results.

You do, however, need to name columns.

I generally name the `id` column in a table as the table name followed by "id", `TableId`, rather than just `id`.  That way, foreign key references generally use the same column name.

As for your question about `key`, it depends on how it is being used.  I am not sure why a separate value is needed from the "id", but this is your application.  Some suggestions for names:

- FilenamePrefix
- EntryName
- Directory
- or whatever

I would caution you from using `UID`.  This tends to be used for [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) or [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: I was looking for the word "slug". Thanks for your help!